# Code example for virtual HID (Human Interface Device)

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth, virtual, hid

I need example of code (or some tutorial) for making virtual HID (Human Interface Device).
If possible with bluetooth integration and made for linux using QT/C++.

Practically, I want to make my own cellphone application which will have few buttons (but it will work as keyboard - sending keystrokes), without requiring server-side application (it will control windows/linux/mac operating systems), and HID seems to me best choice. Unfortunately, I can't find any code samples or tutorials for that.

The thing is I don't know how I am supposed to make service and register it (make it available over bluetooth so OS can recognize it as keyboard and pair with it).

---

So far I have found about BlueZ, but as I mentioned, I cant find any code samples or tutorials.

---

UPDATE: I am trying to make my cellphone (Nokia N9 - Maemo 6/MeeGo OS - Linux) to pretend as HID device via BlueTooth so I can send keystrokes to PC.

Answer (score 1):

The first question that comes into my mind is this usb device made by you ?

I don't understand what making my own cellphone application means . So you have a device that is a cell phone or what please be more explicit

Anyway a solution for you might be the [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/) library works very well on both windows and linux machines.

If you need to study about usb hid devices and how to interact with them you can find a lot of very good tutorials [here](http://www.lvr.com/hidpage.htm).

Please be more explicit in order to help you.

Comment: No, it is cellphone. I have updated what exactly I want to make. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: The second link points to an online shop...Can you update it? I'm interested in reading those tutorials.